# Android Twitter feed friends thumbnails

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

For android,
How can you get the home feed with friends thumbnails with it? Atm I'm using Twitter4j but I can't seem to find anything. I can get the feed but how do I get the thumbnails with it? 
Thumbnails being the users profile pic next to the tweet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `Tweet` object, you can use the Twitter [`getProfileImage`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UserMethods.html#getProfileImage%28java.lang.String,%20twitter4j.ProfileImage.ImageSize%29) method and the user's screen name.

If you have a [`Status`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html) object, you can just call `getUser`, then [`getProfileImageURL`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/User.html#getProfileImageURL%28%29) on the returned `User` object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in reference to the first example, the documentation says that getProfileImage "This method should only be used by application developers to lookup or check the profile image URL for a user. This method must not be used as the image source URL presented to users of your application. "

Comment: @rennoDeniro If you're working from a `Tweet` object, I'd call that method once per user and cache the resulting image.  I think they don't want you calling that method repeatedly because it redirects to the image resource automatically.  You should wrap it in a method that checks to see if the user's image has already been fetched, and use the cached image if it has.